# Garbage Collection to Table

Tags: lua

I was wondering what the best way would be to go about collecting everything from garbage collection and putting it into a table to be sorted through.

```
function CollectGarbageCollection()
  return collectgarbage();
end

for i,v in next, CollectGarbageCollection() do
    print(i,v) -- Data from Garbage Collection
end
```

Code above is just an example.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The whole point of garbage collection is that, after they are collected, objects are gone. You can add a metamethod to your own objects that triggers when they are garbage-collected, but that's it.

---

EDIT: Technically, you could build a patched version of Lua with some hook that gets triggered every time an object gets collected, right before its `__gc` metamethod, but that'd be a bunch of work.